# Difference in the number of supported devices

Tags: android, manifest, google-play

we have app in two versions (pro/lite). Google play shows number of supported devices for pro version 2263 and for lite version 2496. How it is possible?

This is difference in manifest:

### PRO

```
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
```

### LITE

```
 <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait" android:required="false" />
```

Thx for response

Comment: you have lesser filters for the `Lite` version so it turns up more no of devices i believe?

Comment: @Nezam ,but he mentioned those required filters as :false even though there are more filters for PRO version.

Comment: he can try once with what i pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that all your filters are set to `required=false` I'll assume the PRO version is paid and guess an answer here:

There're 2496 - 2263 devices in the world that were only released in countries that does not accept the paid area of the Play Store.

Comment: it's a guess. But unless you do a whole chart comparison study, you won't be able to find out the if it's correct.